# How to open Instagram's camera in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, instagram

How can I open the Instagram camera in my app? not share.
I have tried the setComponent, however the application crashes because Pemission Denied.

In Instagram's AndroidManifest, i want to open MediaCaptureActivity, but it doesn't have intent-filter.

Answer (score 1):

> I have tried the setComponent, however the application crashes because Pemission Denied.
>
> In Instagram's AndroidManifest, i want to open MediaCaptureActivity, but it doesn't have intent-filter.

Then you cannot start it. The activity is not exported, and so third-party apps cannot start it.

Comment: Does there any method provided by Instagram? just like Share function

Comment: @林炳河: Feel free to ask Instagram.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code, hope this will help you out...

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.instagram.android", 
   "com.instagram.android.creation.activity.MediaCaptureActivity"));
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.instagram.android/.creation.activity.MediaCaptureActivity } from ProcessRecord{4293ce20 18844:com.meitu.pomelo/u0a372} (pid=18844, uid=10372) not exported from uid 10128

Comment: I can't do this unless your app is system.